# PHP Echo выводит весь текст после себя, включая код

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

XAMPP PHP 7.3.1
PHP Код

```
<?php
echo "<p>Hello World</p>";
?>
```

Выводит

```
Hello World"; ?>
```

Вместо

```
Hello World
```

Как я понимаю проблема распространенная, однако никаких внятных объяснений по ее устранению не нашел.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ выводит `<p>Hello World</p>` как и должно.

Comment: Проблема распространенная - нет, объяснение - скинули не тот код, что есть на самом деле

Comment: Ctrl+C Ctrl+V. Код именно тот, который есть на самом деле. Причём ошибка наблюдается в любыми функциями вывода, будь до echo или другие принты.

Comment: У вас просто не исполняется php-код.